# PHP image resize on the fly vs storing resized images

Tags: php, performance, thumbnails, image-resizing

I'm building a image sharing site and would like to know the pros and cons of resizing images on the fly with PHP and having the resized images stored.

Which is faster?

Which is more reliable?

How big is the gap between the two methods in speed and performance?

Please note that either way the images go through a PHP script for statistics like views or if hotlinking is allow etc... so is not like it will be a direct link for images if I opt to store the resize images.

I'll appreciated your comments or any helpful links on the subject.

Comment: good question, we could think storing images thumbnails is bad because it creates duplicate images and also useless data when you backup your website.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like premature optimisation. Do you know how many users your site will have/ how much computational grunt your server(s) will have? Go with the simplest (maintenance-wise) option, i.e. resize on the fly, until performance becomes an issue, then figure out from there what to do.

It might be an idea to implement some sort of server side caching of your rescaled images, if they're likely to be repeatedly hit, but I don't think this need extend as far as explicit pre-rendering.

Comment: Thanks, for the advice. Im currently caching all thumbnails as there will be many in one page and left the dynamic resizing for the picture page and the download options.

Comment: You can build your own resizer application easily, check out this repo: https://github.com/sadok-f/flyimg

Comment: I would also add that it's probably best to cache the thumbnails in a separate cache directory. This way you don't mix the thumbnails with the original images, and you can easily determine how much disk space you want to spend on caching. As such, on-the-fly resizing with limited caching will allow you to tune the trade-off between system load and disk space dynamically. Also, the implementation is very modular.

Answer (score 32):

**This is absolutely incomparable matters.**

Resizing images on the fly, in fact, is like running a DoS attack on your own server.   Resize of one usual image require more CPU and RAM than serving one usual request to php script. That's ALREADY a huge impact on performance. Yet a usual thumbnail being shown not alone, but in numbers. So, while showing only one gallery page you are creating dozens of heavy load processes, increasing server load by a factor of ten or more.

Quick and dirty test to prove my words:
Let's try to resize relatively small, 1,3 megapixel image

```
$ /usr/bin/time --format="%MK mem %Es CPU time" /usr/bin/convert angry_birds_1280x800.jpg -resize 100x100 thumb.jpg
10324K mem 0:00.10s CPU time
```

It took us 0,1s, so, showing 10 image previews will eat up a whole second of your CPU time. While properly written PHP gallery page will take around 0,01s. So, with your resize on the fly you are increasing the server load by a factor of 100.

Same with memory. Each resize process will eat no less than 10M of memory (to resize a 100k image file!) with a total sum of 100M. While usual memory limit for the PHP script is merely 8M and it is seldom reached.

That are the real life numbers.

A somewhat funny thing related to this problem:
**Exactly the same PHP user** who easily throwing away 1000000s of CPU cycles at the same time being incredible jealous to spare 1 or 2! It is not a figure of speech, here is an example on what I am talking about:
A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464618/on-the-fly-thumbnail-resize-generation-of-images/) from someone, whose **great concern** at the same time in as negligible thing as [speed difference between Constants, Variables or Variable Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7766486/which-is-faster-constants-variables-or-variable-arrays). And who recently [run into allowed memory size exhausted problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432810/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-in-php-when-allocating-less), as though such a disaster was not enough.

There are TONS of questions and answers on this site, debating nanosecond speed difference of whatever operations, answered with inexhaustible dignity, running tests of millions of iterations to show absolutely negligible difference between one-shot operations of several CPU cycles each.

And at the same time there are questions like this - regarding huge, incomparable difference in terms of performance between two approaches, which looks merely equal to the author.

That's the problem with average PHP user and this site.
The former just have no measure to tell real things from microscopic ones.
Yet the latter have no mechanism for sanity check for the questions - every one answered with equal enthusiasm, even if two questions contradicts with each other (and both with common sense).

Comment: The OP's question per se just asks which way is better, and of course, resizing images beforehand and storing them resized is a huge performance boost and incomparable matters. Not including the fact that when using the on-the-fly method, resizing the same image twice (at least) is worst performance you can get. But, if the on-the-fly image resizing service is used with some CDN in front of it, so each image gets cached it might be a very good option. Actually, I might say that it's the lazy version of storing the resized images to disk.

Answer (score 24):

Dynamic resizing can be a costly procedure (time-wise) depending on the initial size of the images. I've done it in production systems, but when I have the choice, I strongly favor caching to disk. After all, disk space is cheap, and load time is everything on the Web. Even if you simply cache thumbnails at a specific size and do dynamic resizing everywhere else, you can greatly reduce loading times for gallery-style image lists.

Comment: you are right,  i have 400GB available on my live host. I think i'll just store all the resized images. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 18):

I strongly advice you to cache your images, and NOT resize on-the-fly.

resizing of images is very CPU intensive and memory consuming for your server.

If you have a gallery of images that is going to scale on the fly, the page is going to load the images slowly, say something like 3-10 seconds, depends on original filesize.

When resizing it takes about 3 bytes pr pixel of your memory. So If you have an image 1000x1000 to be resized, it will take about 3MB of memory. If your one of your webpages has many of these resize-on-the-fly images, say 20, it will take about 60MB of RAM of your server. 
Maybe not, since most clients only requests 4 images at the time, but 12MB is still a lot for a pageload. I would only scale on the fly if the source image is less that 100x100 px.

TIP: A great lib for scaling and saving thumbs is [PhpThumb](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the input, im defiantly storing the images in the filesystem.