# Fatal error: Allowed memory size in PHP when allocating less

Tags: php, memory

I'm getting this:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 4981690 bytes) in...

That seems a bit odd! From what I can read, it shouldn't happen should it? Isn't meant' to be the other way around. I'm already using a stupidly large memory_limit

Comment: I am wondering who upvoted this not-a-real-question but it still  makes not a slightest sense asking for the "other way" of doing something totally unknown to the reader and stating that "memory limit shouldn't happen"

Comment: @YourCommonSense, what he means is that the amount his script tried to allocate should be larger than the memory limit in order for the error to exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't attempt to allocate it all at once. Let's say our limit is 10 bytes. It will allocate 3, 3, 3 and another 3 - boom: throws the error:

```
Allowed memory size of 10 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3 bytes) in..
```

Answer (score 5):

No, it's allright. The error message might be a mit misleading. The ~5 MB (4981690 bytes) that PHP tried to allocate is not the **total** amount of memory that PHP allocated. It is just the last bunch of memory that it tried to allocate, which it could not do, because of the `memory_limit`.

But this really seems like a lot. What are you doing there? Processing many high-res images?

Answer (score 1):

You tried to allocate additional `4981690` bytes, and had already more than `268435456 - 4981690` bytes allocated before.