# Error in php.ini

Tags: php, memory

We are currently facing a problem, I appreciate if you help me to solve it.

This is the error that we are currently facing:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7680 bytes) in /home/bitrix/www/bitrix/modules/main/classes/general/virtual_io_filesystem.php on line 122
```

What I have done:

1- Increase the memory limit in `php.ini`. ( but it does not work)
2-Restart apache httpd
3- Return back the memory value to its default in website php file `(128m)` from server side ( it still does not work)

Could you please tell me what I have missed?

Comment: did you restart or reload Apache?

Comment: I bet you have some "not-well-written" code somewhere. It's not a solution to increase memory from php.ini because, from my experience, that kind of error is almost never caused by a *real* allocation

Comment: Usually a function that is being repeated endlessly.

Comment: Actually, we are using Bitrix24, a platform for our CRM purpose. I had to change the memory limit into "2048M" in one of bitrix.php files. But, I suddenly faced with this fatal error. I tired to search over Internet to solve it so I found this solution in bitrix website  :  Fatal error: Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted...
The error indicates that PHP is out of memory. Contact your hosting administrator to increase the "memory_limit" parameter in php.ini. I myself changed this parameter in sever side and restart the apache. But it did not work.

Comment: visit----1---->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175153/allowed-memory-size-of-262144-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-24576-bytes     [2]----->>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561066/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-codeigniter-xml