# Caching images with URLs fopr sources using PHP Image Cache

Tags: php, image, caching, memory, out-of-memory

I am using the OMDB API (http://omdbapi.com/) to get movie images. I want to cache these so I can load them from my server.  I am using PHP Image Cache (http://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/). But I am getting the following error:

```
Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 106496 bytes)
```

I have set `memory_limit` in my PHP file to `256`, also have tried `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');` before the script runs and I still get the same error. And the allowed memory size of `262144` never changes.

How can I fix this?

**Solution**

I ended up finding the answer here: [Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24576 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175153/allowed-memory-size-of-262144-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-24576-bytes)

What I don't really understand is why this fixed it? Changing `memory_limit = 256mb` to `268435456` but it has done the trick.

Comment: You used `memory_limit = 256mb` instead of `memory_limit = 256M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I don't really understand is why this fixed it? Changing
>   memory_limit = 256mb to 268435456 but it has done the trick.

That happens because PHP can't understand your syntax. You must provide size properly as '256M' or '1G'. You could also do a trick like ini_set('memory_limit',256*1024); but the default measuring units would be generated by php settings