# Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, memory, composer-php

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 145460 bytes) in /home/legalvis/public_html/wolfpack/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 411
```

I've got this error when trying to execute a rather large script. 
I've tried a few things:

1. Putting `ini_set('memory_limit', '3G');` almost everywhere in my code (including ClassLoader.php)
2. Checking my php.ini file

When I do a `php -i` or `phpinfo();` the allowed size is 3G.

My script is working perfectly locally, but on the server despite the configuration it seems to be failing.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24576 bytes)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175153/allowed-memory-size-of-262144-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-24576-bytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this: ini_set('memory_limit','3072M');
```

Comment: That's weird. But it's working. Don't know why it was not working at the beginning, and why it's working now. 

But thanks!

Answer (score -1):

of the problem : (windows 10) (if you work with xampp)

**PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108872 bytes) in phar://C:/composer/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 83**

you can just run this in cmd  :

**php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"**

if you have 512M or 128M you can just go to c/xampp/php and if you see any file php.ini you can just change 512M or nothing in -1 (-1 it's mean 2G) in all files also repeat this command and verify if memory_limit change or not

also you can run :

**composer update**

happy coding :)

Comment: The `php.ini` setting may be different between CLI and HTTP contexts.