# This request can not be processed via localhost at this time error

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm trying to retrieve data from my database and send them to my view to visualize them in a datatable.

When I first refreshed the page, I could see the result showing my view but then I'm getting this problem:

> This page does not work This request can not be processed via
>   localhost at this time and HTTP ERROR 500

Here's my controller code :

```
public function  index()
{

    $Commandes =  DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')
        ->get();

    return view('detailsCommandes',compact('Commandes'));
}
```

My HTML Code :

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID Commande</th>
    <th>Date Commande</th>
    <th>Numéro de commission</th>
    <th>Année</th>
    <th>Marque</th>
    <th>Modèle</th>
    <th>Finition</th>
    <th>Reférence LC</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  @foreach($Commandes as $Commande)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$Commande->RECID_NADIN}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->Num_Commission_NADIN}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->Annee}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->CodeMarque}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->CodeModele}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->CodeFinition}}</td>
    <td>{{$Commande->REF_LC_BANQUE}}</td>

  </tr>
  @endforeach

</tbody>
```

and here's my route :

```
 Route::get('/detailsCommandes', 'CommandeNadineController@index')->name('details');
```

Can you tell me what's not working here?

Comment: Check in the application logs to see if there are unhandled exceptions logged there.

Comment: I'm getting this : **local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34497832 bytes)**

Comment: I suggest that  you try paginating the query. Looks like you may have a large number of records in the database and loading them altogether in memory is causing that error.

Comment: Indeed, It's the reason for the problem. However, if I paginate my query it will show me just the number of the rows I've mentioned in paginate() while writing my query and in my case I need to retrieve all the records.

Comment: @M_M try this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16175153/allowed-memory-size-of-262144-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate-24576-bytes

Comment: @Iftikharuddin that solution didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at using cursor() when querying and running into memory issues. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#chunking-results

also try select only the db columns you need instead of returning the full record i. e. SELECT * FROM table can be very expensive especially if you are not using all the data