# php good idea to create different image size versions on the fly?

Tags: php, image-processing, header

Recently I heard of the possibility to get different versions of an uploaded image on the fly via php's `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`.

So instead of:

```
<img src="files/myimage-thumb.jpg">
<img src="files/myimage-midsized.jpg">
<img src="files/myimage-original.jpg">
```

you could do:

```
<img src="script/getimage.php?v=thumb">
<img src="script/getimage.php?v=midsized">
<img src="script/getimage.php?v=original">
```

then the script runs and via `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); …` it returns an image which was generated on the server (client?) .. temporarily..

**IS THIS A GOOD IDEA?**

I'm a bit sceptic, because I could imagine that it takes lot more time and performance!?

Comment: **NO.** http://stackoverflow.com/a/9468009/285587

Comment: *dynamically* creating those images for each request is probably a bad idea as it *will* take longer to generate them. The best option is to resize the images and *save* the resized images on the webserver. That way the image only needs to be resized once and they become just 'regular' images

Comment: I suppose you could dynamically create the images once, save them, and then use the saved versions on following requests, but unless you have to make some kind of logic test before presenting an image (access control, retrieval from database, etc) then it makes no sense to go through PHP to serve an image.

Comment: @YourCommonSense maybe I misread, the question you're linking to says that "on the fly" resizing *should be used* until you get too many visitors or it causes your server to 'overheat'

Comment: @cernunnos an option for that is to create a mod_rewrite rule that will only point to the php-script if the requested (scaled) image is not present, otherwise scale and create it

Answer (score 0):

I do that creating a new image and storing on a cache folder then next time if the image already exists i retrieve it or create it.

Something like this:

```
    function resize_image($filename, $width, $height)
    {
    if (!file_exists($filename) || !is_file($filename))
    {
        return false;
    } 

    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $extension = $info['extension'];
            $new_image = 'cache/' . utf8_substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '.')) . '-' . $width . 'x' . $height . '.' . $extension;

            if (file_exists($new_image))
                    {
                      return $new_image;
                    }
                return new_iamge($filename, $width, $height);

}
```