# PDO bind Parameter

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm getting involved in PDO now and theres one thing I try to understand:

If I try:

```
$var = "bing";
$sth-> bindParam(":parameter",$var);
$sth-> execute ();
```

I get no results.

But if I try:

```
$sth-> bindParam(":parameter",$var);
$var = "bing";
$sth-> execute ();
```

I do.   WHY???

Comment: Did you `->prepare` your SQL statement?

Comment: @Martin Yes, I did.

@ Ryan I like the colon writing, because it I think its better to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work both ways.

Double-check your premises, create a **minimal working example** that clearly demonstrates the problem. E.g.

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :parameter");
$var = "bing";
$sth->bindParam(":parameter",$var);
$sth->execute();
var_dump($sth->fetchColumn());

$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT :parameter");
$sth->bindParam(":parameter",$var2);
$var2 = "bong";
$sth->execute();
var_dump($sth->fetchColumn());
```

Most of time, in the process of creation, you will find that simple typo which caused your mistake.

P.S. Either way, better make it just

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ?");
$var = "bing";
$sth->execute([$var]);
var_dump($sth->fetchColumn());
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. I tried it again and everything worked perfectly well. I don't know, where my problem was the last time. It never gets boring! ;-)

Comment: Why is just. $var = "bing"; $sth->execute([$var]); better?

Comment: How much writing does it take?

Comment: You're right its shorter, does that also mean, that it's faster?

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned in "faster" things at all.

Comment: I try to make things good, not just 'right'. so faster is a Point

Comment: Every time you are doing a thing "faster" you are doing it wrong. This pointless obsession will lead you to nowhere.

Comment: Okay, I will think about your words. Thank you.  :-)

Comment: JFYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823600/php-image-resize-on-the-fly-vs-storing-resized-images/9468009#9468009

Comment: You got it on the point.  I get what you mean.  Nevertheless I try in some cases (sql querys for example) to get them as fast as I can. Or do you mean optimizing querys is a bad point, too?

Comment: Nope, optimizing SQL queries is a good thing. But still, only if it's not premature optimization out of nowhere. Blunt optimization (like adding useless indexes) will lead to opposite results as well.